# Imprimir por pantalla una cadena dependiente de un valor aleatorio

Tags: python

Intentaba hacer un código que imprimiera por pantalla el "futuro conyugal". Usé la función **random.randint** para asignar un valor aleatorio entre 1 y 20 a **r**, y dependiendo del valor la impresión por pantalla mostraría el texto correspondiente a dicho valor.
Este programa debería de arrojar por pantalla "Mueres solo" si el valor aleatorio de **r** es 1 o 2, igualmente debería de imprimir "Tal vez, cuando salgas de carrera" si el valor aleatorio de **r** es 5 o 6, y así con cada valor aleatorio de **r** en un rango del 1 al 20.

El código no me marca error. Usando un print después de que se le asignó un valor a **r** pude comprobar que sí se le está asignando un valor aleatorio, pero la impresión por pantalla siempre me da "Mueres solo"... Espero que sea el código y no el destino.

```py
import random

def suerte(respuesta):

    if respuesta == 1 or 2:
        return print("Mueres solo")

    elif respuesta == 3 or 4:
        return print("Ella existe, pero tiene novio")

    elif respuesta == 5 or 6:
        return print("Tal vez, cuando salgas de carrera")

    elif respuesta == 7 or 8:
        return print("Ya la conoces, pero no te has animado")

    elif respuesta == 9 or 10:
        return print("Ella si te quiere, pero no le gusta tu forma de ser")

    elif respuesta == 11 or 12:
        return print("Ella está enfrente de tí")

    elif respuesta == 13 or 14:
        return print("Está fuera de tú nivel")

    elif respuesta == 15 or 16:
        return print("Olvidalo")

    elif respuesta == 17 or 18:
        print("Ya casi se te hace")

    elif respuesta == 19 or 20:
        return print("Se te va a aventar hoy")


r = int(random.randint(1, 20))
print("Tu destino dice que... ")
print (r)

f = suerte(r)

print(f)
```

Comment: Yo diría que falta la pregunta. Sólo has puesto un trozo de código sin explicar qué hace, qué debe hacer, o por qué no funciona. Sólo el título da alguna pista, pero deberías traducirlo pues este es el sitio de StackOverflow _en español_.

Comment: Pequeña pista: Las condiciones con `or` deben hacerse completas, algo asi: `elif respuesta == 15 or if respuesta == 16:`

Comment: @Saelyth Errata: sobra el `if` tras el `or`

Comment: Cierto, estaba un poco dormido.

Comment: @abufalia: Te agradezco y al mismo tiempo te pido disculpas; intentaba hacer un código que imprimiera por pantalla el "futuro conyugal". Usé la función {random.randint} para asignar un valor aleatorio entre 1 y 20 a "r", y dependiendo del valor la impresión por pantalla mostraria el texto correspondiente a dicho valor. Por ejemplo si a "r" se le asigna el valor aleatorio de 8, el programa debería de imprimir por pantalla "Ya la conoces, pero no te has animado". Espero haber sido más claro, saludos!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es la comparación:

```
if respuesta == 1 or 2:
```

que debería ser:

```
if respuesta == 1 or respuesta == 2:
```

y así con todas las demás.

## ¿Por qué no daba error entonces?

Porque lo que tú habías escrito es sintaxis válida, no es un error, sólo que no hace lo que esperas. Para python es como si hubieras puesto:

```
if (respuesta == 1) or 2:
```

lo cual se evalúa de la forma siguiente. Imagina que `respuesta` vale 8. En ese caso lo que está entre paréntesis sería falso, y por tanto para python la expresión equivale a:

```
if False or 2:
```

y eso, pese a que pueda parecer un error, no lo es, pues Python admite prácticamente *cualquier tipo de dato* como parte de una expresión booleana. La regla general es, si el dato es cero o vacío (en caso de cadena, lista, etc.), equivale a `False`. Si es distinto de cero (o contiene algo en caso de cadena, lista, etc.) equivale a `True`. En tu caso, por tanto, el `2` equivale a `True`. Por tanto la expresión `False or True` es cierta, y entra por esa primera condición.

Y eso ocurrirá independientemente del valor de `respuesta`.

## Alternativas

Otra forma de mirar si una variable toma un valor u otro, que es especialmente compacta si quieres comparar con más de dos valores, es la siguiente:

```
if respuesta in (1,2):
```

Pues en este caso verificamos si el valor de `respuesta` está *en* la tupla `(1,2)`, o sea, si es 1 ó es 2.

Por otro lado el código de tu función es bastante repetitivo. Esto suele ser un síntoma de que podría hacerse con un bucle. Si tuviéramos una estructura de datos en la que, para cada posible valor de `respuesta` estuviera contenida la frase apropiada, bastaría buscar en ella el número para obtener la cadena.

Un diccionario es un tipo apropiado para esto. Las claves pueden ser las tuplas de posibles números y los valores las correspondientes frases. Iterando por las parejas clave-valor obtenemos las tuplas (y podemos mirar si `respuesta` está en ellas) y en ese caso imprimir el correspondiente valor. Así:

```
def suerte(respuesta):
    respuestas = {
        (1,2): "Mueres solo",
        (3,4): "Ella existe, pero tiene novio",
        (5,6): "Tal vez, cuando salgas de carrera",
        (7,8): "Ya la conoces, pero no te has animado",
        (9,10):"Ella si te quiere, pero no le gusta tu forma de ser",
        (11,12): "Ella está enfrente de tí",
        (13,14): "Está fuera de tú nivel",
        (15,16): "Olvidalo",
        (17,18): "Ya casi se te hace",
        (19,20): "Se te va a aventar hoy"
    }
    for caso, frase in respuestas.items():
        if respuesta in caso:
            return frase
```

Observa cómo hemos convertido tu código en datos. Los datos son el diccionario `respuestas`. El código es ahora un simple bucle que busca el caso para devolver la frase adecuada.

> **Nota** En tu función tenías un `return print("blabla")`. Si lo que querías era retornar la frase, sobra el `print()`, pues en este caso estás retornando el valor devuelto por `print()`, que es `None`. No necesitas imprimir la frase desde la función, pues ya lo haces desde el programa principal con el `print(f)` (aunque en tu caso éste imprimiría `None` por lo que acabo de explicar)

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente mi error estaba en el **or**, solo modifiqué los **if** de

```
  if respuesta == 17 or 18:
```

a

```
  if respuesta == 17 or respuesta == 18:
```

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el error. He escrito una respuesta un tanto extensa explicando por qué te entraba siempre por la primera opción, y dándote otras alternativas más "avanzadas" para hacer la función.