# ¿Por qué no salta a la opción que introduzco por el input (en este caso la opcion diaSemana == "jueves")?

Tags: python

El problema es que incluya el día que incluya, siempre va al primer `if`  y pregunta ¿Cuántos alumnos han aprobado?. Da igual el día que ponga ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Muchas gracias y aprovecho para saludar ya que es mi primera pregunta para s**tackoverflow**.

Gracias de antemano

```
fecha=input("Introduce una fecha con el dia escrito/ numero de dia del mes /mes del actual año\n")
entrada=fecha.split('/')
diaSemana=entrada[0]
diaMes=int(entrada[1])
mes=int(entrada[2])
print(fecha)
numApr=0
numAlu=20
diaSemana=diaSemana.lower()

if diaMes > 31 or mes > 12:
    print ("Fecha incorrecta")
else:

    if diaSemana == "lunes" or "martes" or "miercoles":
        print ("Dia de examen")
        numApr=int(input("¿Cuantos alumnos han aprobado?"))
        if numApr <= 20:
            print ("Han aprovado", numApr, "chavalxs")
        else:
            print ("Revisa el numero de notas por alumno, es incorrecto")

    elif diaSemana == "jueves":
        asClase=int(input("¿Cuanta gente ha venido a clase"))
        if diaSemana == "jueves" and numAlu <= asClase:
            print ("Han venido",asClase,"chavalxs")
        else:
            print ("Han venido mas chavales de los matriculados, algo ha pasado")
    elif diaSemana == "viernes" and ( diaMes ==1 and mes==7):
        print ("Empieza nuevo ciclo,cada matriculacion vale 100 chelines")
        nuevoAlumn=int(input("Cuantos alumnos se han matriculado"))
        ingresoTotal= nuevoAlumn*100
        print("El centro se ha ingresado",ingresoTotal,"chelines")
    else:
        print ("Revisa los datos, hay algun error")
```

Comment: cambia a `if diaSemana in ("lunes", "martes", "miercoles"):`

Comment: Primero de todo @eyllanesc muchisimas gracias por tu rápida respuesta. El problema es que no puedo usar in. Solo podemos usar if elif else, split, lower(),upper() :( no se como solucionarlo, solo se puede asi?

Comment: el problema es que el programa no sabe que estas comparando. Deberías poner `if diaSemana == 'lunes' or diaSemana == 'martes' or diaSemana == .....`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @DannyTalent,  recien empiezo con python y estoy un poco perdido, ahora lo he entendido, gracias por tu esclarecedora y concisa respuesta. Tambien soy nuevo en stackoverflow, como puedo agradecertelo?

Comment: Pregunta duplicada. Ver esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297440/131763

Comment: Adicionalmente, no es necesario agradecer en SOes

Comment: @IsaacAureli entonces usa la forma extensa: `if diaSemana == "lunes" or  diaSemana == "martes" or diaSemana == "miercoles":`

Comment: Deacuerdo, de todos modos, le estoy muy agradecido, cualquier cosa remítase a mi perfil. Soy diseñador gráfico si le puedo ayudar no dude.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Imprimir por pantalla una cadena dependiente de un valor aleatorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297381/imprimir-por-pantalla-una-cadena-dependiente-de-un-valor-aleatorio)

Comment: De verás esto es maravillos muchas gracias @eyllanesc gracias cualquier cosa pueden remitirse a mi perfil gracias de nuevo

Comment: @IsaacAureli por favor evita mencionar sobre tu perfil ya que puede ser considerado ruido...

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la primera evaluación de días

```
if diaSemana == "lunes" or "martes" or "miercoles":
```

para python una variable no vacía o con valor 0 es True al realizar comprobaciones booleanas:

Lo siguiente da False:

```
'', False, None, 0
```

En la linea antes mencionada, python entiende esto:

```
si (diaSemana es "lunes") o True o True
```

dicho de otro modo para que lo veas mas visual

```
if diaSemana == "lunes" \
or "martes" \  # esto lo evalúa como True
or "miercoles": # también lo evalúa como cierto
```

si lo que quieres comprobar es si un valor es igual a alguno en una lista de valores debes usar in

```
if diaSemana in ("lunes", "martes", "miercoles"):
```

si por el contrario quieres que no este debes usar not in

```
if diaSemana not in ("sabado", "domingo")
```

tienes una explicación extra en una pregunta similar como referencia Danny Talent en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297440/131763